# Obfuscate Node's Browserify Output

Tags: javascript, node.js, obfuscation

How can I obfuscate my Browserify `bundle.js` as it is generated?

I have tried a couple of obfuscators but they are out dated and do not work anymore.

Comment: Which obfuscators did you try? Did you try [uglifyjs](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/)?

Answer (score 0):

I searched and search for a solution to this problem. In the end I simply used babel to "translate" my ES6 code into ES5 and worked from there. I couldn't manage to get to enforce a newer version of webkit.